# Can't compile ANTLR3 project under cygwin, works fine on OSX

Tags: g++, cygwin, antlr3

I'm trying to compile a simple ANTLR3 project (built using the C target) in Cygwin. I've installed the C runtime library using the standard `./configure`, `make`, `make install` approach, and the libraries appeared to install successfully (the header files are installed in `/cygdrive/e/cygwin/usr/local/include/` and the library file is in `/cygdrive/e/cygwin/usr/local/lib/`.

When I compile with g++ (I am using c++ for the rest of the project - the C++ target does not have the ability to generate ASTs), the files all compile fine but the linking fails. Using:

```
g++ -m32 -o compile Main.o Lexer.o Parser.o
```

gives the error

```
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `_antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `_antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: Main.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Adding the `-lantlr3c` flag to the command does not work either, although the error is different:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lantlr3c
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Finally, keeping the library file in the local directory and using the `-L.' flag also doesn't work:

```
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `_antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `_antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: Main.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The first command works fine on OSX. Anyone got any ideas? I figure that it might have something to do with Cygwin's weird file structure/choice of install location but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to build python3grammar (by Ales Teska) under cygwin,
with C runtime named "libantlr3c-3.4" and gcc-mingw32(ver4.7.0).

Command:

```
gcc -m32 *.c output/*.c -Iinclude -I. -L. -lantlr3c  -o py.exe
```

For this error message; undefined reference to `_antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew'.

This article may be helpful:
http://contrapunctus.net/blog/2012/antlr-c
This works with ANTLR version 3.2 (debian stable), but I also learned today there are some significant C API changes in the latest, version 3.4. For one, antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew must be replaced with antlr3FileStreamNew(filename, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT).

Comment: Yeah, that article was useful. In the end I gave up trying to get it working on cygwin, just worked in an Ubuntu VM instead. I'm gonna accept this answer on the basis that the info you provided about the changes to 3.4 was something that took me ages to find out.